# How can I change my plot so that my major axis is every 12 months rather than every 20 months?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, xticks

I am trying to plot temperatures from January 2010 to December 2019. I am using the Pandas dataframe. I've been able to plot my data fine, it looks like this:

[image: Line plot showing monthly temperatures from January 2010 to December 2019. The major tick marks are every 20 months and the minor tick marks are every 5 months.]

It works, but the "major tick marks every 20 months" makes it hard to read. I was wondering if there was a way I could change it to every 12 months.

My code is this:

```
monthly_data['Months'] = month_names #list containing "jan2010" to "dec2019"
monthly_data = monthly_data.set_index('Months')
monthly_data['temp_f'] = av_temps

%matplotlib inline

ax = monthly_data.plot(style='ko-', title='NYC monthly temperatures in 2010-2019', 
ylim=[0.0, 80.0], figsize = (14,6))

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (°F)')
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='grey')
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid('on', which='minor', axis='x', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.3', color='black')
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to suppress default x-axis behavior of `pandas` with `x_compat=True`

```
import math
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": pd.date_range("2010-01-01", "2018-08-31", freq="1M")})
df["val"] = [math.sin(i) for i in range(len(df))]
df = df.set_index("datetime")

#Plot
ax = df.plot(style='ko-',
             title='NYC monthly temperatures in 2010-2019',
             figsize = (14,6),
             x_compat=True)

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (°F)')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y %b"),)
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='grey')
ax.tick_params(rotation=0)
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():    
    label.set_horizontalalignment('center')
    
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.grid('on', which='minor', axis='x', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.3', color='black')
```